# Windows 10 - Read-only File Flag Has No Effect

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, read-only

I want to disable files from being overwritten in Windows 10. I figured that was the use of the 'Read-only' file flag. But after enabling it, it appears programs (at least the program it opens in) can still overwrite it with absolutely no issue.

Isn't Windows supposed to prevent the file from being overwritten? Or is it per the application to respect this 'Read-only' flag?

(Specifically, this is .gm81 files being overwritten by GameMaker 8.1, although this shouldn't matter as I imagine the Read-only file flag *should* be program agnostic).

Comment: If you want to change the permissions of a file, so it cannot be modified by a specific user, you have to change the permissions of the file.  You can do this by modifying the ACL of the file itself.  As for the reason it's not behaving the way you expect, the problem is that the files on the file, have been explicitly define to allow the file to be modified within the ACL.  The read-only attribute is program agnostic, permissions to a file on Windows are per user, not per based on the application.

Comment: TBH, it sounds like you need a document versioning system.

Comment: Windows Explorer will happily overwrite read only files **because** it removes the read only flag from the file. On a directory CMD.exe respects the read only flag (prevents you deleting the folder) but explorer doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From experience the read-only flag prevents programs from *directly* overwriting files. A file can be opened with "write" permissions and the read-only flag should block that.

It does not prevent the file being deleted (by any program) and then a *new* file being created with the same name.

Depending on the program in question it is entirely possible that they simply read a file entirely into memory and then close it on loading, and simply delete and fully export everything from memory  to a new file on saving.  Programs *should* honour the honour the read-only flag, but they are not obligated to.

Comment: I know this is how it works in general as I have written several macros for various programs that exploit this behaviour to force saving over read-only files. Basically a couple of lines of code that say "if this is read-only then delete it first, and now save it using the same name."

Comment: I've written programs that just turned off the read-only attribute if it was detected on, and reenable it after the write.

Comment: @FrankThomas I already had a subroutine that could nuke any given file or directory for other reasons (mainly clearing out obsolete data prior to regenerating a new set) so by the time I'd gotten to "I could just run `attrib` on it" it was too late for the "subtle" approach to programs refusing to write over read-only files... :)

Comment: Almost like the read-only flag is pretty useless these days